# Firebase Stuck on `Run your app to verify installation` for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have done all the steps but still I am stuck here on this screen.

Though the crashes can be seen inside in `Crashlytics panel`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to run it in a real device.

Comment: Yes did on device as well as simulator.

Comment: That happened to me, I ran a few times the app on a real devices, and then it worked, maybe it's a Firebase thing

Comment: I don't understand if setup isn't done then how it's showing the crash report.

Comment: Does the app compile and run? Can you include your podfile as well as your App delegate code? Also, did you download the GoogleService-Info.plist and drag it into your project?

Comment: Yes I can show my Podfile. It's reporting the crash to firebase webapp.

Answer (score 4):

Hey make sure you have called:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 
    FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

If this doesn't work try sending some data to firebase like so:

```
Analytics.logEvent("This is a test", parameters: [
            "Test1": "tester",
            "Test2": "tester"
            ])
```

This will send analytics data to Firebase

Comment: Tried nothing changed.

Comment: Did you run the app and install the pods?

Comment: Yes obviously I did

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was using Firebase/Analytics 6.11.0 and when i changed to 6.8.2 fixed the problem

Google Release Version 6.12 on November 5th, 2019. I would recommend update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The actual trick here is to use **latest** version of the pod(s).

Firebase forces you to use the **latest** version of the pods in order to complete the final step check.

Let's say you had pods with specific versions in Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '= 6.27.0'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '= 6.27.0'
```

Remove explicit versions

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
```

Remove app from device / simulator. Rebuild, run app. Check back on Firebase site.

After this, you can set any version in Podfile, execute `pod install`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **SwiftUI**, looks like you need to use manual logging of events using `Analytics.logEvent(_, parameters:)`. Place below in your AppDelegate and it should then verify installation.

```
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventAppOpen, parameters: [:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my podfile with this line and it fixed the problem.
`pod 'Firebase/Analytics','6.8.1'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that a `pod 'Firebase/Core'` blocked newer version installation of `pod 'Firebase/Analytics`. As soon as I removed `pod 'Firebase/Core'` everything worked like Google described.

Comment: But what if I need Firebase/Core ?

Comment: I think they integrated it into any Pod you can install for Firebase. I only do pod 'Firebase/Admob' and pod 'Firebase/Analytics' and Firebase Core is installed too.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your app from the device or simulator. Include `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'` within your `PodFile` and run `pod update`. After doing that, a reinstall and relaunch solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had `GoogleMaps` and `GooglePlaces` pods installed as well as the `Firebase`. And I had the following on my `AppDelegate`:

```
// Configure Firebase APIs
FirebaseApp.configure()
    
// set google api key
GMSServices.provideAPIKey(Constants.googleMapsApiKey)
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(Constants.googleMapsApiKey)
```

> **Once I commented the lines that rovides the api keys. The test worked !!**

Don't know if returning them back would mess things up again. still on it !!

Answer (score -7):

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="true"/>
```

Comment: The question is about iOS